# Работа с элементом ComboBox JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть небольшая программа, в которой есть ComboBox элемент.
Данный элемент принимет 5 значений для примера.

```
ComboBox emailComboBox = new ComboBox();
emailComboBox.getItems().addAll("A","B","C","D","E");
```

Мне очень нужно записать в переменную результат выбора элемента из данного Combobox, что бы потом значение из этой переменной использовать далее в программе.

Я пытался воспользоваться различными решениями. Одно из них сработало на получение элементов, но не могу записать результат выбора в переменную.

```
emailComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
.addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                        String oldValue, String newValue) {
        System.out.println("Value is: "+newValue);
    }
```

});
Как из данного метода я бы мог вытащить переменную, результатом которой является выбранный пункт из выпадающего меню CombobBox?
Заранее спасибо!